# How to use ConnectableObservable to prefetch and then use processed data with different subscriber

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable, rx-android

In my app, I need to load a large amount of data as soon as the application starts. Also, I need to receive an event when data has been loaded in some fragment/activity.

I am using RxJava `ConnectableObservable` for that purpose. I used `replay()` as I need same data for multiple subscribers.

Psudo code:

```
 Observable.create(emitter -> {
            try {
                Data next = getDataFromDb();
                emitter.onNext(next);
                emitter.onCompleted();
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
                emitter.onError(e);
            }
        }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER)
        .toList()
        .compose(applySchedulers())
        .replay()
```

Now If I want to pre-fetch data, should I `subscribe` in application class and then in Activity/Fragment use `connect()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
observable = Observable.create(emitter -> {
        try {
            Data next = getDataFromDb();
            emitter.onNext(next);
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            emitter.onError(e);
        }
    }, Emitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER)
    .toList()
    .compose(applySchedulers())
    .replay(1)
    .autoConnect()
//start your prefetch
observable.subscribe()//you should better add some log to see the process

//In your Activity
observable.subscribe(/**Your Subscribe**/)// here you will get the replayed value
```

Notice that :

1. you should keep the same instance of your Observable, otherwise you can't get your replayed value
2. you should use other overload of `autoConnect()` for example `autoConnect(int numberOfSubscribers, @NonNull Consumer<? super Disposable> connection)` and get the disposable(Subscription for RxJava 1.x) for your upstream source .